# How to play an alarm sound when 'no interruptions' is set in lollipop?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I was previously able to play a tune in my app, even when the volume was off like so:

```
    AudioManager amanager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxVolume = amanager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
    amanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM, maxVolume, 0);
```

... which is good in an alarm clock app for obvious reasons. Unfortunately, in lollipop this no longer works when 'no interruptions, not even alarms' is turned on: The phone stays silent.

However, the stock alarm clock still works properly even with 'interruptions off', and I wonder what they do differently.

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure of what does this, but the source code should help: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/DeskClock/+/master (yes, designing a good alarm is complex)

Comment: First gues, the internal clock app has special permissions so it can access android internals (I see for example WRITE_SETTINGS). Other I see this news post about a company who circumvented this issue: https://support.pagerduty.com/hc/en-us/articles/203565440-Using-Override-System-Volume-on-Android-L-Lollipop-5-0